# Django criar paginção usando Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Quero fazer upload sem refresh da paginação usando ajax

Tenho uma table onde mostra 5 itens por pagina o objetivo é ao mudar de página não fazer refresh na página para mudar para a seguinte

Nas views:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No template a nav da paginação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Foi cortado código desnecessário, apenas deixado o código que é necessário da paginação

Comment: Utiliza Datatable dá aqui uma olhada. https://pypi.org/project/django-datatables-view/

Answer (score 0):

Django template language trabalha fazendo novas requisições server-side, para carregar apenas o resultado através de ajax você vai precisar criar a chamada por javascript e uma api que te retorne os itens da tabela no formato json.
Sugiro utilizar algum framework (vue, angular etc) e criar um componente de paginação.

Answer (score 0):

O Django até possui um paginador que pode ser usado mas ele não fará como você quer, assim a dica é usar o Django REST Framework junto com alguma solução em JS, por exemplo o DataTables (neste caso é necessário usar uma biblioteca que cuida para que o DRF crie um JSON compatível cim ele).